# Getting specific part of JSON data

Tags: php, json

I want to use PHP to parse JSON data from an external site. This code is working as intended:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

... and

```
echo $obj->title;
```

... is posting the title from the JSON data (Far Cry Primal):

```
{"id":241408,"title":"Far Cry Primal","url":"http:\/\/www.prisguide.no\/produkt\/far-cry-primal-241408","price":547,"priceCount":13,"image":{"100x100":"http:\/\/img.prisguide.no\/1678\/1678079\/original.77x100mt.jpg","300x300":"http:\/\/img.prisguide.no\/1678\/1678079\/original.232x300t.jpg","500x500":"http:\/\/img.prisguide.no\/1678\/1678079\/original.jpg"},"category":"Spill","categoryId":32,"manufacturer":"Ubisoft Montreal","specifications":"Xbox One, Action, 18+, Ubisoft","specificationsFull":[{"id":96,"name":"Plattform","type":"select","sectionName":"Generelt","value":[{"id":45275,"value":"Xbox One"}]}
```

But I need to access more elements, like the last one (scroll all the way to the right) - value: Xbox One.This has it's own ID, but im not sure how to access it.

Any hints?

Comment: I very much doubt this is working as intended, using `json_decode($json, true)` gives you an array, not an object.

Comment: you can use foreach of `$obj->value` and get the data easily

Comment: Sorry, removed "true", its working without that - but there is more data with the "value" attribute (every single one is bounded with an ID, but I didnt want to post miles of similar code) - and what I want is the value of the specific ID

Comment: Try $obj['specificationsFull']['value']['value'];

Comment: Also, your current json string is an invalid json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, your JSON isn't valid so I can't test it but I'm sure you get the idea.

```
foreach($obj as $items)
{
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        foreach($item as $value)
        {
            foreach($value as $key => $value)
            {
                echo $key . ': ' . $value;
                echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very close! I just think I need to go one level "deeper", as its printing: `value: Array` and I need the content inside that array

Comment: I've updated the answer to include another level. Please accept this answer if you're happy it's helped :)